# How to implement Lua thread for Sleep function

Tags: c++, lua

I am running into a problem in my game engine right now.
I want to be able to call Sleep(number_of_seconds) from .lua file (1 only) and halt the execution of the lua file, WHILE the game is running and rendering / updating.
When the sleep is done, the .lua file will return execution.
Is this possible?
All the best, 
Aldo

p.s.
I guess this can be implemented with C++ `<thread>`but I couldn't find a solution for now:/

Comment: Is sleep a must? You could use an update function and some GetTime function and check if enough time has passed.
Or you could use a time-based callback from your engine. I'll elaborate on this if this is a good solution for you.

Comment: unfortunately my teacher asks me to implement a Sleep AND a Timer function, so I have to do it:p

Comment: Then your solution is to run the lua script in a separate thread and do synchronizing with mutexes or semaphores.(probably mutexes)

Comment: Ok thanks I'm going to look into that. Do you have any links of implementation or something to clarify it?

Answer (score 1):

Make the lua script a coroutine and have sleep yield

```
if(now()-timestamp > sleepDuration){ // overflow-proof timeout check
    int oldtop = lua_gettop(L);
    int yielded = lua_resume(L, NULL, 0);
    if(yielded == LUA_YIELD){
        lua_pop(L, lua_gettop(L) - oldtop - 1); //only keep timeout value
        sleepDuration = luaL_checkinteger(L, -1);
        timestamp = now();
        lua_pop(L, 1); //pop timeout
    }
}
```

You can have `sleep()` yield multiple values so other wakeup reasons are possible. You can also pass that wakeup reason as a parameter to resume in so the script knows what woke it up.